# lseek() and read() proper usage

Tags: c

I am reading in a "non human readable file" full of structs. I have declared my struct that is a known member of the file.  I want to read the file from the begging to the sizeof the stuct populating the fields.  I don't understand why my out put is zero for all the struct fields. I have looked at the man pages of these functions and I believe I am using them correctly, so am I just not accessing the fields correctly from the buffer, or? please see below code snippet.

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // make sure you were given an image
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("no image\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int fs_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

    // make sure you can open the image
    if(fs_fd == -1)
    {
        printf("image is busted\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct superblock *mySB;
    mySB = malloc(sizeof(struct superblock));
    mySB->size = 0;
    mySB->nblocks = 0;
    mySB->ninodes = 0;

    char buffer[4096];
    if(lseek(fs_fd, 0, SEEK_SET));
    read(fs_fd, &buffer, sizeof(struct superblock));

    mySB->size = buffer[0];
    mySB->nblocks = buffer[4];
    mySB->ninodes = buffer[8];

    printf("Size: %u, nblocks: %u, ninodes: %u\n", mySB->size, mySB->nblocks, mySB->ninodes);
}
```

ok, suggestions taken into consideration, though in truth I'm not concerned withe good error checking at this point.  the following results in a seg fault as i'm sure this is not reading into the struct correctly, but I am trying to use the suggestions.

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // make sure you were given an image
    if (argc != 2)
    {
         printf("usage: file.img");
         return -1;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

    // make sure you can open the image
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error> ");
        return -1;
    }

    struct superblock *mySB;
    mySB = malloc(sizeof(struct superblock));
    read(fd, &mySB, sizeof(struct superblock));


    printf("Size: %u, nblocks: %u, ninodes: %u\n", mySB->size, mySB->nblocks, mySB->ninodes);
}
```

Comment: Why the intermediate step with the buffer?  You can `read` directly into a variable of type superblock as well.

Comment: Please show the definition of superblock, and the `xxd` output of your binary file.

Comment: You ignore bytes 1-3,5-7,9-etc of `buffer` in assignments like `mySB->size = buffer[0]`, please use `memcpy` or read directly into mySB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why no compilable testcase along with an example file?

```
int fs_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

// make sure you can open the image
if(fs_fd == -1)
{
    printf("image is busted\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Wrong. At the very least use perror to tell what the user what the error is. What's up fs_fd name anyway? Standard name is mere fd.

```
struct superblock *mySB;
mySB = malloc(sizeof(struct superblock));
```

Consider sizeof(*mySB);. Null-checks can arguably be ignored.

```
mySB->size = 0;
mySB->nblocks = 0;
mySB->ninodes = 0;
```

What's the point of this if you initialize same fields below?

```
char buffer[4096];
if(lseek(fs_fd, 0, SEEK_SET));
```

What? Not only teh offset is already at the beginning, you are just ignoring the error (if any) in the worst possible way. If you really need to call this and ignore the error, do (void)lseek(fd_fd, 0, SEEK_SET).

```
read(fs_fd, &buffer, sizeof(struct superblock));
```

How about some error checking. If you read only teh size of the struct, why having the buffer be 4096? What if the struct is larger?

```
mySB->size = buffer[0];
mySB->nblocks = buffer[4];
mySB->ninodes = buffer[8];
```

Nobody knows how this struct looks like. It *seems* you have 4-byte sized fields. But you only read ONE byte for each field here.

You likely can just read into the structure instead. If you really want to have an intermediate buffer you have to properly calculate offsets as padding could have screwed you over. Google for offsetof and padding.

Comment: what you've said is helpful, however when I try to set the fields int mySB by reading directly into it, and not initializing first, I get a seg fault when i try to print. as in they are not getting set. so I so suppose the more appropriate question is how do you read directly into the struct and set the fields?

Comment: Print what? You can just read(fd, crap, sizeof(crap)); and there you go. I fail to see how printing ints from here can be problematic. I can suggest you show your code and once more suggest you show the structure.

Comment: print the values now stored in the structure's fields after the read (I wish to know what they are) .  Everyone's comments have been helpful, if a little snide...and I have it working correctly. I will share the structure because everyone is so curious, though to me I dont see why you need it: struct superblock {
  uint size;         // Size of file system image (blocks)
  uint nblocks;      // Number of data blocks
  uint ninodes;      // Number of inodes.
};
 thank you once again, though i think in the future I should maybe state that my C skills are not that great